# How to make emacs work properly without having permission on $HOME directory

Tags: emacs

On one server I don't have permission to create new files inside my home directory. 
Whenever I start emacs I gets following error:

```
Creating directory: permission denied, /home/vivek/.emacs.d/
```

How to start emacs using different directory or without .emacs.d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the value of the HOME environmental variable, emacs will treat the directory specified as if it were your home directory.  From bash:

```
HOME=/some/other/place emacs
```